# Vue.js and Laravel difference return json and resource

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm confused about the difference between the two. It seems like they offer the same functionality. Here is an example of how each of their controller look like.

**Return json controller**

```
 public function index() {
    $department = Department::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    return response()->json($department);
  }
```

**Return resource controller**

```
public function index() {
     $department = Department::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
     return DepartmentResource::collection($department);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the first method triggers the model method **toArray**.

```php
<?php

class Message 
{
   public function getExcerptAttribube() {
     return '...'; // strip HTML, etc ... 
   }

   public function toArray() {
      return [
         'id' => $this->id,
         'title' => $this->title,
      ]
   }
}
```

This makes it easy to programmatically hide, casts or append properties when turning models to JSON.

This can of course also be done with mutators like $appends, $hidden, $casts, $with.

Eloquent mutators: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

The seconds method with a resource allows to move that logic to a separate object.

```php
<?php

class MessageResource extends JsonResource
   public function toArray($request) {
      $message = $this->resource;
      $message->load('user'); // auto-load relation
      $message->append('excerpt'); // use $message->getExcerptAttribube() to make an excerpt
      $message->append('is_read'); // use $message->getIsReadAttribute()

      return $message;
   }
}
```

This is useful to move a lot of business logic outside the model itself. This also avoids querying extra SQL-records every-time you use $with.